# How to handle the type of the value returned by lodash.omitBy?

Tags: typescript, lodash

`omitFalsyFields` generic function will remove the key which value is falsy(`''`, `undefined`, `null`, etc...) of an object.

```
import _, { Dictionary } from 'lodash';

export function omitFalsyFields<T extends Dictionary<any>>(params: T) {
  return _.omitBy(params, (k) => !k);
}

interface CreateUserParams {
  name?: string;
  email: string;
}

const params: CreateUserParams = omitFalsyFields({ name: '', email: 'example@gmail.com' })
```

I expect the type of its returned value is `CreateUserParams` type.  The value of `params` is `{ email: 'example@gmail.com' }`, so the type is compatible with `CreateUserParams`.

But, got TS type error:

> Property 'email' is missing in type 'Dictionary' but required in type 'CreateUserParams'

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&module=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAfQDRwN5wCLAMY2BAOwEMoBPOAXzgDMoIQ4ByAGwgBMiBnAC0YG4AUAICmAD0iwaAVwK58BOPWAwAYkWadSK4MOZtOAHgAqcMTGEF9mHHkIlSBogVIA+FwAowJIiE4AuOCMASjQBODgoYRgpKAUEADolGAAhUk9vXxR3AGsQgF4XOABCXMEKIWACcyhqImxhOABhSKJzAFVOYSgABQzOUPDiEGEAfgDOGChKgHNBcOEQImBmccmZsqFsQgm4LygffyaW9s6evrg8xRBlNQ0tHT1Od3Qh4QDGRhQFpZWmMR8wMxhAABaaLZbxLYgRiUIJCIA)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make this function generic, you can do the following:

```
export function omitFalsyFields<T>(params: T): Dictionary<T> {
  return _.omitBy(params, (k: any) => !k);
}
```

Now you can pass any type and it should be applied to the input and output

```
const params = omitFalsyFields<CreateUserParams>({
  name: "",
  email: "example@gmail.com"
})
```

But one caveat about this is that `omitBy` returns a `Dictionary<any>`, even doing `Dictionary<T>` it will always casts to any because it's very hard to infer types at runtime if not impossible sometimes, therefore if you want to assign a custom return type or assign the generic **T** type as output, do the following:

```
// note that T is an alias for you generic type
export function omitFalsyFields<T>(params: T) {
  // use the "as" keyword to override the returned type from omitBy.
  // With partial you change all properties of T to optional,
 // as omitBy removes falsy properties it makes sense to apply this utility
  return _.omitBy(params, (k: any) => !k) as Partial<T>;
}

const params = omitFalsyFields...
console.log(params.name) // undefined
console.log(params.email) // example@gmail.com
```

Doing so, the specific type will be passed to the output as well, take a look at the [complete example](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-n71i65?file=/index.ts).